# CSS Images and the Z Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

So I have a total of 3 images being displayed, 2 of them need a higher Z Index than the other image so the 2 images are above the one image. I have done this in my CSS:

```
#cover {
    background: url("my_name.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    z-index: 10;
}

#twitterImg {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #3C3C3C;
    margin-left: -330px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#youtubeImg {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #3C3C3C;
    margin-left: 410px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    z-index: 21;
}
```

Although it produces this: [image]

Where the image is under the cover image. 
I don't think the 2 images are children, they should be independent although here's my HTML just in-case you'd like to review it.

[Pastebin Because HTML is weird on stack overflow](http://pastebin.com/xZH00R4G)

[Full CSS](http://pastebin.com/5E1wSGkW)

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` will not work while you not set the position so set `position` to `relative` .. you can try this

```
#twitterImg {
    position : relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #3C3C3C;
    margin-left: -330px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    z-index: 20;
}

#youtubeImg {
    position : relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #3C3C3C;
    margin-left: 410px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    z-index: 21;
}
```

or you can set

```
#navigation {
    position : relative;
    width: 638px;
    height: 80px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 21;
}
```

This is the image that everything works fine in your website http://darklegionrp.byethost24.com/

[image]

Comment: Will I need to change the cover class to have a z index of 1? As I still get  [this](https://i.gyazo.com/f9268f739fd571a37a4318b36d36777b.png)

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz you always can play with z-index up to your need in website .. you can make code z-index: 1; and the #navigation  to z-index: 2  for example

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. [Link!](http://pastebin.com/VRHt4aiC) [Error](https://i.gyazo.com/6f5c0d46315e01cac715b64155eee272.png)

Comment: [Here!](https://jsfiddle.net/x5hrqe5e/6/) Beware the sound. [Fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/x5hrqe5e/6/embedded/result/)

Comment: So it works in JSFiddle, but not on my website? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5hrqe5e/9/) [Website](http://darklegionrp.byethost24.com/)

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz I think it works just fine in your website as I see here .. try to clear  your browser cache  or test in other browser

Comment: Still nothing after a cache reset! Please help, I'm sure its a simple correction and Id ideally want to get this done by the morning

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz you already have no problems in your website link you sent it to me  .. your website works as you expected in my browser .. I'm using chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit) .. and your animation is working back of your image and twitter and youtube images is appears nice as well .. http://darklegionrp.byethost24.com/

Comment: @GenaratedPixelz I update my answer with your website image as it appears in my pc .. and to believe you have a browser issue .. its already worked on jsfiddle